# Could not load type 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.IdPartPair from assembly OpenXMLPowerTool , Version 4.5.3.0, Culture=neutral,

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We need to convert word document to html. Using OpenXMLPowerTools, code was working in .NET Framework 4.6. But after migrating to .NET6, we are getting above exception for HTMLConveterSettings while converting images from the document.

Any resolution for this issue?

Comment: Why?  Microsoft Office output to XML is not really OpenXML.  And you cannot read XML into Office.  Outputting from Office to XML can be done, but it is not very pretty.  Try manually saving the word to xml and then use a text editor to see the results.  XML and HTML are both meta languages but in most cases they are not interchangeable.  You can save Word directly to HTML so it can be viewed with a browser, but you do not use OpenXml library.  The word SaveAs has option to save as HTML.